# Time/memory efficient work with std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector

I'm currently implementing Astar algorithm in which each node is stored in vector and then returned to outer object - like this:

```
class Astar
{
   std::vector<Node> find()
   {
      std::vector<Node> open;
      std::vector<Node> closed;
      std::vector<Node> path;

      //A_star algorithm working with open and closed vectors
      //when path found fill path with push_back()

      return path;
   }
}
```

In outer object code looks similar to this:

```
class Foo
{
   Astar astar;
   std::vector<Node> path;
   void findPath()
   {
      path = astar.find();
   }
   //do stuff with path
}
```

Reason why `findPath()` exists is that I want to make it run in another thread, so if path is found - do stuff, else - maybe it's time to find path (simplifying). Thing that bothers me is `path = astar.find();` because it can be a lot of copying (not to mention that `push_back()` in `Astar` class also copies value).

Possible solutions I thought about are: passing Foo's `std::vector<Node> path;` reference as an argument to `Astar`'s `find();` or make friendship in between `Foo` and `Astar` so `Foo` could access private path. Prior to me is time and memory efficiency (time over memory).

Comment: If you benchmark it, I'm sure you would be surprised. Do some research about *copy elision* specifically, and *return value optimization* in general. As well as some research about *move semantics*.

Comment: You may want to use `reserve()` to reduce the copying and moving in `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

First remember that C++ allows for [Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), so returning a vector by value is not in itself a problem.

However:

- It is costly to do repeated allocations of objects which might be allocated just once. So you could theoretically have the method take a reference or a pointer to some buffer for the path, which must be guaranteed to have enough memory. That way, the outer code only even allocates once and may re-use its buffer for repeated calls.
- It is costly to construct an object which you don't plan on using it. So you might want a method named `has_path(const Node& source, const Node& target)`, or even a stand-alone function with that functionality.